# Emacs Magit not working after OSX Catalina upgrade

Tags: magit, osx

Since upgrading my mac to Catalina yesterday, I managed to get Emacs working again after allowing Ruby access to all files in the settings, and most of it works fine, but I can't get Magit to recognise the repo that it is in. `C-x g` simply does not work, so I tried `M-x magit-status` in the minibuffer and it asks if I want to create a repo, but I'm already in the the right place, still working on the same things I was working on last week. The only change is the Mac OSX upgrade (work machine so enforced).

Comment: very silly question, but you did have a project file open when you "M-: magit-status" ?

Comment: Not a silly question actually, but I am definitely inside my project as was trying to commit. I've just installed xcode in case that was the issue, but still nothing. I can use git in terminal, but magit is not connecting

Comment: check out the value of magit-repository-directories to be sure thats not an issue. (C-h v magit-repository-directories)

Comment: @RichieHH so this does appear to be the issue, as "Its value is nil". I've tried 'magit-list-repositories' also and it returns that I need to customize 'magit-repository-directories'. I don't know how to do this though, it's always just worked in the past.

Comment: and it should continue to do so. nil means using current directory afaik.

Comment: make 100% sure the file you have open is in the git repo hierarchy and not some copy elsewhere...

Comment: Definitely in the right place, I have a terminal window open and checking everything. I've added emacs to have full file access along with git, ruby and now also xcode just in case, but Magit still askes to make this a repo. I tried accepting making folder as repo, but still nothing.

Comment: And when you saved the buffer you then went to the command line and git shows the correct diff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED: thanks to all who commented here it helped me find a solution. So first thing to do with Catalina is to give full file access to emacs, this is done in settings - Security & Privacy - /Full Disk Access. Then install this at the start of your settings: https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell. Apparently this is a common mac issue, but I've not had it till now and it is actually a FAQ in the Magit docs which is where I got the Purcell package tip from.

Comment: don't forget to mark your solution as the Answer.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days